# can Maple simplify a Fourier series?

Tags: simplify, maple

how can I use Maple to simplify
`sum ( sin(n*t) / n, n=1..infinity)`
to `(Pi-t)/2` for `0 < t < 2*Pi` ?
Thanks for your help
Pavel

I tried

```
assume (0 < t and t < 2*Pi):
s := sum ( sin(n*t)/n, n=1..infinity):
simplify(s);
```

I expected `(Pi-t)/2`

The result was  `-1/2 I (-ln(1 - exp(x~ I)) + ln(1 - exp(-I x~)))`

Can this be simplified to `(Pi-t)/2` ?

Comment: This is about the actual use of your CAS, not a programming question related to your CAS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way (Maple 2023.0).

```
simplify(evalc(sum(sin(n*t)/n, n=1..infinity)))
   assuming t>0, t<Pi/2;

    -1/2*t+1/2*Pi
```

Comment: Can you briefly explain this answer?

Comment: And how can this be done using Mathematica? I tried `FullSimplify[ Sum[Sin[n*t]/n,{n,1,Infinity}], 0<t<Pi/2]` but the answer is just `I/2 (-Log[1 - Exp[-I t]] + Log[1 - Exp[I t]])` instead of `(Pi-t)/2`.

Comment: ryanwebjackson, can you explain precisely what details you want explained? note that `evalc` is often useful for finding real trig representation of ln/exp expressions that might also contain I. Another similar use of it is for turning real roots of cubic -- in radical form -- into trig form without I present. Etc.